# Can ZFS onlinux be upgraded to newer versions

Tags: linux, zfs

I want to install zfs on linux on a clean NAS installation, but I would really like the native encrytion feature that comes with the next (0.8) release.

My question is; If I install the current version, will I be able to upgrade to 0.8 and turn on encryption when it comes out, or should I rather wait?

Comment: Why do not install Solaris in such case? You will have the last possible version of ZFS code incorporated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can upgrade an existing pool's on-disk-format to support encryption, by running:

```
zpool set feature@encryption=enabled testpool
```

Or to enable all new on-disk features, simply do:

```
zpool upgrade -a
```

However, you *cannot* turn on encryption for a pre-created filesystem: you have to use `zfs create -o encryption=on <filesystem>` at the time of creation in order to encrypt your data. If you want to start using ZFS now, you'd have to create a new filesystem after upgrading and copy existing data from your unencrypted (old) dataset into the (new) encrypted one.

This and many more ZFS encryption administration topics are covered very nicely [in this article](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2017/01/08/zfs-encryption-openzfs-zfs-on-linux/).